# Prometheus get count of up metric 0 for give alert

Tags: alert, monitoring, prometheus

I have alerts setup on Prometheus where there are different jobs in the alert.I want to find how many times the alert was fired over last week, given the job name.So there is a alerts name "A" and there are multiple jobs "B","C","D" under that, I want to know how many times alert "A" was fired for job "B" in last week.

If I use following expression :

```
sum by(alertname) (changes(ALERTS_FOR_STATE[1w]))
```

It gives me total alerts fired in last week but since there are multiple jobs in that, I am not able to figure out how to get count only for specific job.

I would like to know if there is some other way to achieve same thing?

Answer (score 1):

What about the following query?

```
sum by (alertname, job) (changes(ALERTS_FOR_STATE[1w]))
```

Comment: it shows only 1 count but the alert i am having in context is fired a lot of times.

Comment: Following is my alert:-    alert: XYZ
expr: up{job="XYX"} == 0
for: 15s, Some how when i am using sum by query given by you, it is not detecting this alert. I have read that changes(ALERT_FOR_STATE) works only if ti goes from pending to firing. My alert went to firing but since it is not showing count correctly i think it is not going to pending.Can you help me here?

Comment: Try to increase "for: 15s" to "for: 2m".

Comment: that i cannot change. I need to monitor my server so that it should not go down for more than 15 sec. Does it not fit use case of prometheus?To see how many times alert is fired?

Comment: What is your scrape_interval? The default value is 1m. Maybe you should scrape faster.