# How to get "UP" metric count=0 for last week from Prometheus?

Tags: alert, monitoring, prometheus

I want to know how many times "UP" metric for a given job is 0 over last week?
I am using following query

```
up{job="XYX"} == 0
```

This list out some of the entries where it was 0 but from that it is not clear, when these alerts were fired.
How can I get count of all such "UP" metric with value 0 over last one week, from which I want to conclude, how many times server was down in last week.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for an availability metric.

Use the following query to know the percentage that XYZ job was available in the last week:

```
100*avg_over_time(up{job="XYZ"}[1w])
```

If you want to know the unavailability just do the following:

```
100-100*avg_over_time(up{job="XYZ"}[1w])
```

Comment: it does not print anything, I have a alert that fires if that UP metric is 0 for 15 seconds as i shared above.When i am summing by alert name , it just shows 1 count over last week but there have been 10-15 email notifications for alert firing,I want to get sum of all such notifications

Comment: I used the wrong metric in the answer, I just fixed it.

Comment: i am trying to get something https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65617748/prometheus-get-count-of-up-metric-0-for-give-alert , see my comment

Comment: Ok, but what about this question? Did the answer work?

Comment: it shows me some metric and i assume it is availability metric, But it shows me for one job. So i have two alerts with different name and their job name is same. So how can i know this availability is for which alert?One alert is for server health monitor and one for server has internal failure like external dependecny,So same job name and two different alarms,What exactly will this query will tell me?

Comment: what exactly i want i how many times the alert that monitors my rest server is fired.

Comment: If you use {job="XYZ"} it'll show the metric only for this job, right? If you want for every job just remove the restriction. I suggested using the "availability" metric instead of counting how many times the alert fires.